# Trigger for push notification in android

Tags: apex, trigger, mobile

I am trying to create a push message notification. It is being called from a after update trigger on a custom object.

I have used the following code for IOS

```
Messaging.PushNotification msg = new Messaging.PushNotification();
    String pushMessage = Label.Push_Notification_Message;
    Map<String, Object> payload = null;

    for(Object__c objectOld : objectListOld){
        for(Object__c objectNew : objectListNew){ 

            if(objectOld.Id == objectNew.Id && objectOld.Status__c != objectNew.Status__c){

                 payload = Messaging.PushNotificationPayload.apple(objectOld.Name+':'+pushMessage+' '+objectOld.Status__c+' to '+objectNew.Status__c, '', null, null);
                    try{
                        msg.setPayload(payload);

                        String owner = objectOld.OwnerId;
                        String lastmodifiedById = objectNew.LastModifiedById;

                        Set<String> users = new Set<String>();
                        users.add(owner);
                        users.add(lastmodifiedById);
                        msg.send('Test_App', users); //Add the name of the connected app
                    } 
                    catch(SObjectException e) {
                        System.debug('SObjectException caught: ' + e.getMessage());    
                    } 
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        System.debug('Exception caught: ' + e.getMessage());    
                    }                        
            }
        }
    }
```

For Android, the following was written in the implementation guide

'Unlike iOS,
Android doesn’t have special attributes or requirements for the payload; it just needs to be in JSON format. In Apex, you create the
Android payload as a MAP object' with the following example.

Map androidPayload = new Map();
androidPayload.put('number', 1);
androidPayload.put('name', 'test');

Here I am trying to understand what

androidPayload.put('number', 1);
androidPayload.put('name', 'test');

the above refers to and what needs to be passed to the map.
I want to implement the same thing I did for IOS(given above).

Answer (score 0):

For IOS, payload is prepared as below:

```
Map<String, Object> payload = Messaging.PushNotificationPayload.apple(objectOld.Name+':'+pushMessage+' '+objectOld.Status__c+' to '+objectNew.Status__c, '', null, null);
```

For android, it should be:

```
Map<String, Object> androidPayload = new Map<String, Object>();
androidPayload.put('alert', objectOld.Name+':'+pushMessage+' '+objectOld.Status__c+' to '+objectNew.Status__c);//pass alert attribute
androidPayload.put('sound', '');/pass sound attributes...in same way other attributes
```

Only difference is IOS needs a specified format which but Android just accept information in json format.
Here is the working code for android that may help you... https://github.com/developerforce/WearablePack-AndroidWear/blob/master/samples/QuoteDiscountApproval/src/main/salesforce/unpackaged/triggers/QuoteApproval.trigger

Comment: Thank you. I would like to understand one thing here. Here does the JSON key values need to be in a specific ? If so from where do I get the key values and the format

Comment: JSON key value should be the information that you would like to send your android app...if you see in the given shared code on Github, information like quote name, opportunity detail and opportunity owner info is sent to android app....I would suggest give a try practically and debug at android end...